# Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, android, make, ubuntu-for-android

Here is one problem shown when I tried to `make` my android 2.3.7 OS sytem by typing `make -j8` under the directory:

```
/home/paultsai/android/aosp-2.3.x/

Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: external/webkit/WebCore/bindings/scripts /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/WebCore/HTMLNames.h] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: external/webkit/WebCore/bindings/scripts /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/WebCore/HTMLElementFactory.h] Error 2
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: external/webkit/WebCore/bindings/scripts /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/WebCore/V8HTMLElementWrapperFactory.h] Error 2
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix these problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t) and then:

```
 sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl
```

or using cpan:

```
cpan
```

At the prompt `cpan[1]>`, type

```
install Switch
```